# I want to change the path of android:name=".MainActivity" to "settings.MainActivity"

Tags: java, android-activity, android-manifest, src

AndroidManifest.xml
I want to change the path of
android:name=".MainActivity" to "settings.MainActivity"

`android:name=".MainActivity"`to
`settings.MainActivity`

I created a "settings" folder inside the "src" file and moved the "MainActivity.java" file inside the "settings" file. There is an error.
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
R cannot be resolved to a variable